# find コマンドで出力したリストから１行目と./を削除してファイル出力したい

Tags: linux

```
% find .
.
./ft_magic
./ii
./test1
./.test0
./test3
./test2
```

Comment: このコマンドで解決しました
```
find . | awk 'NR>1{print substr($0,3)}'
```

Comment: 回答はコメント欄ではなく **個別の回答** として投稿してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

```sh
$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.8.0

$ find . -printf '%P\n' | sed 1d
```

Comment: コマンドを実行したところ下記のエラーが出ました。findのバージョンの問題でしょうか？
またバージョンを確認しようとすると下記のエラーが出るのですがなぜでしょう？
```
% find --version
find: illegal option -- -
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]

Comment: Mac OSX をお使いですね？ OSX にインストールされている find コマンドは BSD 由来のもので、GNU 版 find コマンドとは異なります。

Comment: Macとlinuxは違うということですね。printfをprintに置き換えて実行したところ下記のエラーが出ました。
```
% find . -print '%P\n' | sed 1d 
find: %P\n: unknown primary or operator
```
変数がおかしいようなのですが何が問題ですか？

Comment: OSX デフォルトの find コマンドは '%P' を解釈してくれません。別途、GNU find をインストールする方が良いかと思います。もしくは Itagaki さんの回答の様にすると良いかと思います(bash をお使いであれば)。

Answer (score 0):

bashなら

```sh
shopt -s dotglob ; find *
```

`shopt -s dotglob` は `*` でカレントディレクトリの`.`で始まるファイルやディレクトリも展開させるためです。必要なければ要りません。
`shopt -s dotglob` を解除するには `shopt -u dotglob` です。

teratailでも同じ質問をされましたね。
teratailでは推奨されていないことですので適切に対処してください。
[ヘルプ｜teratail（テラテイル）](https://teratail.com/help#posted-otherservice)